# Adding UI elements WP7

Tags: windows-phone-7, user-interface

How to add programmatically N elements to WP7 control, so that they are under each other (currently i have all in one place and they overlay each other)?

```
//this code N times
TextBlock block = new TextBlock();
block.Text = message.Body;
ContentPanel.Children.Add(block);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
private Ellipse GenerateEllipse()
{
    Ellipse element = new Ellipse();
    element.Fill = new SolidColorBrush(Colors.White);
    element.Height = 8.0;
    element.Width = 8.0;
    this.ContentPanel.Children.Add(element);
    return element;
}
```

and after that how you call the method in a *for* cycle.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

Create a StackPanel and add your controls to it.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.stackpanel.aspx

Answer (score 1):

The basic problem here is that the x and y co ordinates of the elements you are adding are all the same. Hence they all come in one place. As Grid layout does not take care of this.

The answer to this is to use stackpanel or individually define the uielement.margin; value.
The margin is basically a thickness element.
I was having the same problem but then made use of changing the x and y coordinates of my elements.
I used
uielement.margin.left= previousUiElement.margin.left+6;
uielement.margin.top= previousUiElement.margin.top+36;

change the 6 with whatever your requirement is.